# Web Scraping on Some Websites are not Working on Power Automate

Tags: web-scraping, power-automate

I am not able to perform web scraping by using Power Automate. It did work on some websites but some are not workable.

The one that I would try to scrap data from is: https://apps.sfc.hk/edistributionWeb/gateway/EN/circular/products/product-authorization/

I have no coding experience. If Power Automate cannot work on this website, I would be much obliged if anyone can advise for any alternative. Thank you!